# Is there a way to increase JavaScript's onmousemove event's update speed?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple drawing script in HTML and JavaScript. I'm doing so by creating a div over the entire window, and then tracking the mouse position by having that div's onmousemove event call updateFunc() so that when you hold down left click, a red, circular div element is created and appended per update to resemble a brush.

The problem is that the updating of the onmousemove event is so slow that if you move the cursor too suddenly, there are wide gaps between each created div element. Ideally, creating a line, no matter the speed you move your cursor, should be as smooth as possible. Is there a way to do this using this method, or should I try something else?

```
<div onmousemove="updateFunc();" id="background" style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:100%;" onmousedown="isDown = true;" onmouseup="isDown = false;"></div>
<div id="test1" style="width:10px;height:10px;background-color:red;"></div>
<script>
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
var isDown = false;
function updateFunc() {
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    document.getElementById("test1").style.left = (x - (Number(test1.style.width.slice(0,-2)) / 2)) + "px";
    document.getElementById("test1").style.top = (y - (Number(test1.style.height.slice(0,-2)) / 2)) + "px";
    if (isDown) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.top = (y - (Number(test1.style.height.slice(0,-2)) / 2)) + "px";
        div.style.left = (x - (Number(test1.style.width.slice(0,-2)) / 2)) + "px";
        div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        div.style.width = "10px";
        div.style.height = "10px";
        div.style.borderRadius = "200px 200px 200px 200px";
        var body = document.querySelector("body");
        body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look at [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) instead of using a `<div>`

Comment: Suggestions: don't scan the DOM in your update function. `document.get*` is slow. do it outside your mouse move function.

Comment: It's not JavaScript, it's the web browser. The "mousemove" event is triggered pretty frequently, but you're creating an element and updating the DOM on every event. That causes the whole page to be re-rendered.

Comment: [this article is exactly what you need right now](http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to ***accelerate*** the browser firing `mousemove` events.
You could use some basic trigonometry, after two points are created, simply connect the two points with the missing DIV... wait, did I just said DIVs?
DOM should not be used to make paint applications (well, unless you're creating a 32x32 favicon generator, but even than...) **use `canvas`. It's really easy to get you started**.
Canvas will have the same "problem" though. It *will* connect your mousemove points with a line, but if you're fast with your mouse - the line will look like a polygon's edge. In such case, some bezier or quadratic curve might help. The end result will be a faster and more UX-plesant app. The user can also download his own drawing (save as image) once creatively exhausted.

Here's a demo that uses `canvas`, and `quadraticCurveTo`:

```js
var pen = {
  color: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)", // Set desired color
  size: 3                        // Set desired size
};

var pts = [];
var isDown = false;
var isTouch = false;
var cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
var cvs2 = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = cvs2.getContext('2d');

function setCvsSize() {
  cvs.width = cvs2.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  cvs.height = cvs2.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}

function penDown(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  isTouch = ev.type === "touchstart";
  ev = isTouch ? ev.touches[0] : ev;
  isDown = true;
  pts.push({
    x: ev.clientX,
    y: ev.clientY
  });
  drawPoints();
}

function penMove(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev = isTouch ? ev.touches[0] : ev;
  if (isDown) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
    ctx.drawImage(cvs2, 0, 0); // Draw to inmemory cvs2
    pts.push({
      x: ev.clientX,
      y: ev.clientY
    });
    drawPoints();
  }
}

function penUp(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  isDown = isTouch = false;
  pts = [];
  // Save state to in-memory cvs2
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  ctx2.drawImage(cvs, 0, 0);
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
}

function drawPoints() {
  var i = 0;
  var i2 = pts.length > 1 ? 1 : 0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = pen.size;
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(pts[0].x, pts[0].y);
  for (; i < pts.length - i2; i++) {
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
      pts[i].x,
      pts[i].y,
      (pts[i].x + pts[i + i2].x) / 2,
      (pts[i].y + pts[i + i2].y) / 2
    );
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = pen.color;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// EVENTS

cvs.addEventListener('touchstart', penDown);
cvs.addEventListener('mousedown', penDown);
cvs.addEventListener('touchmove', penMove);
cvs.addEventListener('mousemove', penMove);
cvs.addEventListener('touchend', penUp);
cvs.addEventListener('mouseup', penUp);
window.addEventListener('resize', setCvsSize);

// INIT
setCvsSize();
```

```css
*{margin: 0;}

#canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Yep, and if the OP does use lines to connect each point they can use `ctx.lineCap = 'round';` to "smooth" the edges on the line

Comment: @Nick yes absolutely, if *round* is the desired pen shape :)